# How to run commands when a docker image runs?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, acl, consul

I have a consul docker image which is a part of a `docker-compose` environment.

I have to run the command `consul acl bootstrap` inside the docker container, I believe mentionining it in `command` or `entrypoint` will override the default commands set for consul, how do I execute it in addition to the default commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option in docker-compose to allow you to run a command after a container is started.

What you can do is to build your own image that will execute the actions you want on startup. To do this you need to:

1. Find out the default startup of the container (the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` combined).
2. Create a shell script that will invoke the entrypoint with the desired parameters, after which it will invoke your commands.
3. Create a Dockerfile that is based on the original image, copy the shell script in the image and changed the entrypoint to your script
4. Add your image and dockerfile to the docker-compose (change the current consul image to point to your image and build script)

Here is example of a entrypoint shell script what can be used to kickstart your specific script. Place your code in the `execute_after_start()` function.

**entrypoint.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

execute_before_start() {
    echo "Execute befor start" > /running.txt
}

execute_after_start() {
    sleep 1
    echo "Execute after start" >> /running.txt
}

execute_before_start
echo "CALLING ENTRYPOINT WITH CMD: $@"
exec /old_entrypoint.sh "$@" &
daemon_pid=$!
execute_after_start
wait $daemon_pid
echo "Entrypoint exited" >> running.txt
```

The script will start the `execute_before_start`. When this commands are over,  will start the original entry point with the arguments provided with `CMD` and in parallel (this is the `&` at the end of `execute`) it will start `execute_after_start`. When `execute_after_start` is over, it will wait for the original entry point to stop.

I use `sleep` in the example as a simples way to assure some delay so the entry point can take the commands. Depending on the entrypoint, there might be smarter ways to assure that the entrypoint is ready to take the commands.

Comment: thanks for response but If I am going to override the default cmd, why not add it to the docker-compose file directly?

Comment: Depending on what your additional commands are. Certainly you can overwrite them, but If you start having more commands to execute, very soon the overwriting in `docker-compose.yaml` will become more complex and less maintainable. On the other hand, creation of new docker image based on the original is easier to maintain and allows more complex commands, changes and additional files. You can create the dockerfile and add it to `docker-compose.yaml` to automate the build of the image, so apart from creating the docker file, no extra work is required.

Comment: ok, so I should create another entry point file, say `consul-entrypoint`, which should invoke the `docker-entrypoint` , (the default entry point of consul image) with the required parameters, and set `ENTRYPOINT ["/consul-entrypoint.sh"]` in the Dockerfile ?

Comment: Yes, you create another shell script `myentrypoint.sh` that is calling first `consul-entrypoint.sh` then running your commands (ex. `consul acl bootstrap`).

Comment: `"Cmd": [ "agent", "-dev", "-client", "0.0.0.0" ]` is the `CMD` for consul image, this is passed as parameters to `docker-entrypoint` of consul image, how do I ensure this is passed to it from my docker-entrypoint ?

Comment: @AjaySabarish I gave you a boiler plate so you can start working on your script

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, its not possible in compose to run additional commands after a container has started.

Alternatively you can explicitly specify the master token's secret ID by specifying [`acl.tokens.master`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#acl_tokens_master) in the Consul server's configuration. The easiest way to do this with the Docker image is to pass the configuration using the `CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG` environment variable (see [Docker-Consul: Using the container](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/f375487/consul#using-the-container)).

For example:

```yaml
---
version: "3.8"
services:
  consul:
    image: consul
    ports:
      - "8500:8500/tcp"
    environment:
      CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG: >
        {"acl": {"enabled": true, "tokens": {"master": "A8D89992-A3DB-46E3-A528-8F97CFEDB183"} }}
```

This has the obvious downside of hard coding a token into your Compose configuration, but also avoids the complexities of trying to run `consul acl bootstrap` using a custom entrypoint.

You only need to provide this environment variable when the cluster is first initialized. After that, Consul persists this token data in a Docker volume mounted at /consul/data. Any modifications to the tokens (including the master token) need to be performed using `consul acl token` or the [`/v1/acl/token`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/acl/tokens) API endpoints.

Comment: How do I know the token to pass, without running `consul acl bootstrap`? Should I manually copy/paste it?

Comment: @AjaySabarish the token is just a random UUID. You can generate one on your own using the CLI tool `uuidgen`.

Comment: Thanks, got it now

Comment: Would you mind marking my response as an answer to your question if it resolved your issue?