# Is there a way to automatically backup your database when issuing docker down command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Tried to search the Docker documentation, however, I cannot find anything that directly relates to a backup on the `down` command. Additionally, I see you can add your own `command` script in the yml on `up`, so I was hoping that there might be something similar for `down`?

Comment: How would you address this problem without Docker?  In general, there's no shutdown hook for containers, especially when that would otherwise force the container to stay alive so you can run the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your own entrypoint script that will create an exit hook. You can see more details on the steps of building custom image with a custom entrypoint in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66632662/how-to-run-commands-when-a-docker-image-runs/66634649#comment117984869_66634649).

In your case, the entrypoint will look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

execute_on_finish() {
    echo "Execute on finish" 
}

trap execute_on_finish EXIT

echo "CALLING ENTRYPOINT WITH CMD: $@"
exec /old_entrypoint.sh "$@" &
daemon_pid=$!
wait $daemon_pid
execute_on_finish
```

#### Note

> Since the backup process is a long operation, and docker will execute a `kill` if the process doesn't shut-down in 10s, you will need to send option to the `stop` not to kill the container with `-t`. See more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/)